# WebView not Loading Facebook url in android

Tags: android, facebook, url, webview

I have a webview in my activity and i want to load facebook url in that webview,I have tried as below,But its not working,I dont know what is the problem,My code is as below:
**xml**

```
  <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wv_fb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

**code**

```
url = "https://www.facebook.com";
        wv_fb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_fb);
        hdr = (Header) findViewById(R.id.hdr_fb);
        hdr.title.setText("Facebook");
        menu = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.menu_fb);
        menu.setSelectedTab(3);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv_fb.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wv_fb.loadUrl(url);
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: did u give the internet permission in manifest file

Comment: if no add this line  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in manifest